# Which test to use for analysing dependency of continous variable on nominal variable from the same sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm analysing responses from a questionnaire survey. I have two variables one is continuous variable age, where each responded, had written his own exact age to response and then I have a nominal variable where they answered yes or no to some question. I want to do a statistical test to find out whether the age is dependent on this nominal variable.

Both my variables are not normally distributed.
My n = 44.

Which statistical test should I use?

Updated, boxplots of my data:
[image: boxplots]

Comment: It would be good if you could tell us what you are interested in. The t test BruceET recommends below is a test for equality of means. If that is what you want, great. But maybe you are interested in tests for the equality of medians or 90% quantiles.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a Welch two-sample t test in the following
circumstances: (a) The sample sizes for the Yes and No groups
are small and the distribution of ages is nearly normal, or (b)
Sample sizes are large and age distributions are not badly skewed
and show no very extreme outliers.
If a two-sample t test is not appropriate, then consider a two-sample
Wilcoxon (rank sum) test.

For example: You might have data with summaries shown below, where `x`s answered Yes and `y`'s answered No:

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  28.00   36.75   44.00   45.86   51.00  102.00 
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  24.00   35.00   40.50   40.84   45.00   72.00 
boxplot(x, y, col="skyblue2", pch=19, names=T)
```

[image]

We can see from the boxplots that both Yes = 1 and No = 2 groups
have positively skewed ages--even with a couple of very senior
citizens in the Yes group. With 100 subjects in each group, as here, we can
feel comfortable using a two-sample t test with such skewness and outliers.

From
the boxplots it already seems that ages are higher in the Yes
group. A Welch two-sample t test shows a highly significant
difference:

```
t.test(x,y)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 3.0393, df = 173.2, p-value = 0.002739
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.759998 8.280002
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
    45.86     40.84
```

It may be worth mentioning that a two-sample Wilcoxon
test also detects a significant difference. (Of course,
it would be cheating to run both tests and pick the
smallest P-value, but either test on its own should
suffice.)

```
wilcox.test(x, y)$p.val
[1] 0.008732757
```

*Notes:* (1) Your real data will be different from my
simulated data, but I hope it is clear what kinds of
tests are appropriate, and how to perform them in R
statistical software.

(2) In case you are interested, I show below how I simulated
my fake data for illustration.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = round(rgamma(100, 5, 1/5)+20)
y = round(rgamma(100, 5, 1/4.5)+20)
```

(3) The 'robustness' of t procedures, using samples of large $n,$
is largely due to the near-normal distribution of sample 
means of $n$ observations from the population in question,
as 'promised' by the Central Limit Theorem. 
It is fair to wonder
if the CLT can 'digest' skewness as pronounced as in our
sample `x`.

By bootstrapping the distribution of means $A = \bar X$
one can get a good idea. The histogram shows $B = 10\,000$ means
$A$ of $n=100$ values resampled from `x`. The red curve is the density
of the best fitting normal distribution. The distribution of $A$'s is not exactly normal, but close enough to warrant using a t test.

```
a = replicate(10000, mean(sample(x,100,rep=T)))
hist(a, prob=T, br=20, col="skyblue2", 
    main="Dist'n of Resampled Means of 100 for Yes")
  curve(dnorm(x,mean(a),sd(a)), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed post, it's great. Just one thing, I have tested my data for normality and they are not normally distributed.

Comment: OK. Glad I addressed the robustness of t procedures against nonnormality. Hope your real data are not more severely skewed than my fake data.